# Link to a target iframe doesn't display until another area of the window is clicked

Tags: mod-rewrite, iframe, hyperlink, mousehover, cursor-position

My site uses iframes. `Frame A` has a list of items for selection, when one is selected it shows details in `Frame B`.
The link from frame A is like this:

```
<a href="https://www dot mysite dot com/subjectname/detailname/-x?a=$a&b=$b etc., target="Frame B"
```

The `subjectname` and `detailname` are to make the url friendly and do not correspond to directories at `mysite.com`, instead I have a mod rewrite which recognises the `-x` and redirects to the appropriate php program that produces the detail for the selected item.
My problem is that after clicking on the item in `Frame A`, the detail displays in `Frame B` sometimes, but intermittently (more often than not) it won't display until I click elsewhere (anywhere) in the window, i.e. it appears to be hidden. It will also display if the cursor goes over a 'hover' sensitive place elsewhere in the window.
This behaviour happens in Chrome on my windows machine but appears ok in Safari on Apple and Chrome on my Android phone.
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that it works fine in my localhost development environment (Apache,php,mysql, on my windows PC) with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The linked-to program was not correctly accessing the required Styles sheet (this was not obvious to me as the default style looked fine. After I corrected this access the problem disappeared!